# Pandas from_dict Returns TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
testProps = {"Key1":[],
             "Key2":False,
             "Key3":True,
             "Key4":[],
             "Key5":False}
```

I want to convert it to a Pandas DataFrame with

```
newTestProps = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(testProps,orient="index")
```

but it is throwing me the following error.

`TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()`

When it should be creating a DataFrame like the following:

[image]

Which is bizarre because I've had these two lines of code in my program for a long time and it hasn't thrown this error until now. Is it possible that there's a bug with Pandas?

Comment: do you expect these to be the output? 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4, Key5]
Index: []

Comment: @DejeneT. Added a picture to show what the DataFrame should look like after running from_dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the dataframe you can use next example:

```py
testProps = {"Key1": [], "Key2": False, "Key3": True, "Key4": [], "Key5": False}

df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': testProps.keys(), 0: testProps.values()})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Index      0
0  Key1     []
1  Key2  False
2  Key3   True
3  Key4     []
4  Key5  False
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```
newTestProps = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(testProps.keys(), testProps.values())), columns=['index', 0])


print(newTestProps)



     index   0
0  Key1     []
1  Key2     False
2  Key3     True
3  Key4     []
4  Key5    False
```

Answer (score 1):

one of ways you can do it as ,

```
import pandas as pd

testProps = {"Key1": [], "Key2": False, "Key3": True, "Key4": [], "Key5": False}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data=testProps.items(), columns=['index','0'])

print(df)
```